# Shaping a Div with css

Tags: html, css, border, shapes

I want a really weird shaped div and I've read around the web for shaping divs but they only show how to do triangles and circles and things like that. No one really explains why the thing is happening that they do.

[image]

Please note: It can't be just a border, as there is supposed to be text inside it.

I sure hope someone could help me :)

I have tried several things but none were doing what I wanted them to do.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.samuelrossille.com/css-shape/#1142AAy0z-10z-4z13z4z0_20z2z-4z4z0

Try this site, you can generate your own shapes. 
I made you a little start.

Veel succes

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly something I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome! I would appreciate it if you accepted this answer if it helped you @user3086787

Comment: Lets try finding out how that works.

Comment: Choose a shape from the left by clicking on it once. Then click in the center field, and resize it. And at the end you can copy the code from the right field.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired results using CSS3 borders and transform properties. More details including working examples can be found here:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: That was the website I was refering to in my post, it doesnt explain how it works and why and it cant explain how to develop my own shape.

Answer (score 1):

use two div's. give border-radius to inside div. and place text inside your div.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to slice your shape in Photoshop or any other program as transparent .png and include it as css background for that div

Comment: I know that's a possebliity, but I want to use pure css as it will make the website lighter :)